# how to expand touch area of button using delegate or gestures?

Tags: android, android-button

In my application, there are 4 buttons with *WrapContent*, therefor button hit area is very less.

I need to increase hit area using delegate or gestures. I am trying to increase touch area by using Layout of button and button size manually.

Comment: i need only using touch delegate or gestures

Comment: we cannot use padding because it effects other views.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a bigger image with transparent parts. Make an image for the button which is larger than the actual button and make the surrounding areas transparent. Now, wrap_content will include that area also and touch gestures will be detected over the whole area while the user will only see a small button.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add some padding to the buttons (or any View, really), either in XML or dynamically. The padding is transparent and still receives touch events for the View.

Alternatively, you can use [TouchDelegate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html), but I personally find a bit redundant and needlessly complicated for such a simple task.